# What is `kern.num_files` in `sysctl`?

Tags: macos, posix, sysctl

I'm trying to find out total number of currently open file descriptors (or any file related objects) on current OS.

My current betting is `sysctl`(3), and I think `kern.num_files` does the job. But I'm not actually sure what it means, and I can't find any manual page entry or standard spec for `kern.num_files`. This makes me nervous.

- `kern.num_files` is listed on `man 3 sysctl`, but only names are listed and says nothing about what it actually means.
- Command line `sysctl -a`(2) lists and report some value for `kern.num_files`.
- `sysctl.h` does not define a name looks like `kern.num_files`
  although it even contains names like `KERN_FILE` that are considers private/deprecated.

Is this actually the count of system-wide open FD? Where can I find any spec for this?
If `kern.num_files` is not the number, what is recommended way to get the total open FD count?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33715/which-command-controls-the-open-file-limits

Comment: @Olha It seems your link is about "max limit" value. I'm looking for "current open files descriptor count". Thanks anyway.